# Cauchy Product with reindexing

Tags: real-analysis, summation, cauchy-product

Suppose I have the following:

$$xe^{xz}A(x,z)$$

where

$$A(x,z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n(z)}{n!}x^n$$

and $a_n$ is a polynomial in $z$

Taking the Cauchy product (since $e^{xz}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}x^n) $ gives

$$x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{a_k(z)z^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{a_k(z)z^{n-k}}{n!}x^{n+1}$$

I need to reindex with respect to $n$ since I want a power series that has terms $x^n$, so I think this yields

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\frac{a_k(z)z^{n-1-k}}{(n-1)!}x^{n} $$

Would this be the correct reindexing?

Edit: I changed the denominator to $(n-1)!$ from $n!$ since I think I missed it...

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: Is there another way that keeps the inner summation bounds untouched or goes from $k=1$ to $n$?

Comment: I think I don't understand the question :)

Comment: It's okay....  I think it's irrelevant anyway...  Thanks for the help!